# Is there a VBA function that allows me to set the number of hours in a day to less than 24 hrs?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dateadd

I am trying to create a VBA loop that will run through a set of orders. For each order I have a duration in hours. For each record, it will add the duration to the start date time and create the end date time. The end date time will be the start date time for the next record etc.

I have this working using the `dateadd` function but that assumes that the production happens 24 hrs a day.

How can I specify that we only work 12 hours a day for example, so any work that goes past say, 7 pm in the evening will spill into the next day?

I tried using `dateadd` in a loop and it works but I cannot specify 12 hours in a day

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from Combined_Prod_PO_2_T ORDER BY SEQ")

'Define Changeover master as RefChangeover recordset
Dim EffStart_DateTime As Date
Dim EffEnd_DateTime As Date
Dim FamFrom As String
Dim FamTo As String
Dim changeover As Double
Dim RefChangeover As Recordset

'rs.OpenRecordset
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    EffEnd_DateTime = rs.Fields("EFFEND_DATETIME")
    FamFrom = rs.Fields("PRODUCT_FAMILY")
    Debug.Print FamFrom

    rs.MoveNext
    If Not rs.EOF Then        ' making sure that the "next" line exists i.e. stop at the second last line
        FamTo = rs.Fields("PRODUCT_FAMILY")
        Debug.Print FamTo
        Duration = rs.Fields("DURATION")

        Dim sqlcmd As String
        sqlcmd = "select sum(hrs) from (SELECT hrs from AP_Changeover_Master where [FROM] = '" & FamFrom & "'" & " and [TO] = '" & FamTo & "'" & " union select distinct 0 from AP_Changeover_Master) "

        Debug.Print sqlcmd
        Set RefChangeover = db.OpenRecordset(sqlcmd)
        changeover = RefChangeover.Fields(0).Value
        Debug.Print changeover

        'If Not rs.EOF Then

        rs.Edit
        rs("Effstart_datetime") = EffEnd_DateTime
        rs("EffEnd_DateTime") = DateAdd("n", (Duration + changeover) * 60, EffEnd_DateTime)
        rs("changeover") = changeover
        rs.Update
    End If
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

When your DateTime value goes over 12 hours you could divide that value by 2.

Start Time = 05/01/2019 8:00AM 
End Time = 05/02/2019 8:00 AM

The Total time taken here is 24 hours. But since you only work 12 hour days, dividing by 2 will give you, 12 hours.

If you worked 8 hour days, you could divide by 3 to return only 8 hours and so forth.

Keep in mind your value with this solution will be in a decimal format, not a Time format

```
Dim ActualTimeTaken as Decimal

rs.Edit

If rs.("YourTimeTaken").value > 12 Then

    ActualTimeTaken = rs.("YourTimeTaken").Value / 2
    'Do whatever you need here.


End If

rs.Update
```

Comment: I have a similar production process, and I do what @ChanceFinley has suggested, I store the duration of the production activity as a decimal rather than a number of hours.  My code than tracks the running total for any activities that are less than 1 in duration, and moves to a new day once the running total exceeds 1, and then I subtract 1 from the running total and carry on adding.

Comment: As a further suggestion, you may find @Gustav WorkDayAdd code helpful, rather than DateAdd.  His code allows for weekends, holidays etc to be adjusted for.